# How to deduce the number of solutions?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, polynomials, quadratic-forms, quadratic-residues

We consider a prime number $p\equiv 3 \pmod4$ and $\mathcal{D}(1,p):=\# \{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{F}_p^3 \mid  x^2+y^2+z^2\equiv 1 \pmod p\}$

By a powerful formula I found that $\mathcal{D}(1,p)=p^2-p.$

Now I have to deduce $\mathcal{F}(1,p):=\# \{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{F}_p^3 \mid  x^4+y^4+z^4\equiv 1 \pmod p\}$ . Maybe I can start with writing $x^2=u,y^2=v,z^2=t$. So the equation becomes : $u^2+v^2+t^2\equiv 1 \pmod p$ but I think there are other cases because I did not use $p\equiv 3\pmod 4$ enough.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the fact that $p\equiv 3 \bmod 4 $ you can in fact identify that there are exactly the same values in the same proportions for $\{a_i^2\}$ and $\{a_i^4\}$. Note that for some primitive root $g$ of $p$, the quadratic residues are represent by $g^{2k}$ and the fourth powers by $g^{4k}$, which collects the same group of numbers over a double range of powers, eg. $g^2 \equiv \left(g^{(p+1)/4}\right )^4$

Therefore $\mathcal{F}(1,p)=\mathcal{D}(1,p)$

Comment: Could you develop more that fact ? Do I have to use LQR theorem ? Thank you in advance !

Comment: @Maman does this work for you?

Comment: @WillJagy Not so, I checked $\bmod 11$ and it is $110$

Comment: alright, actually looked at my previous answer, it is $p^2 - p.$ Some days it doesn't pay to get out of bed. Hmmm, when I wrote out the numbers by hand, I was doing $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 0$ rather than $1.$ Sigh.

Comment: It's clearer so thank you

Comment: If we have $p\equiv 3 \pmod 4$ it means that $-1$ is not a quadratic residue $\pmod p$ ?

Comment: @Maman correct, which also means that when $x$ is a quadratic residue, $-x$ is not.